# how to send bulk push notifications to some users using azure hub

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification

I am quite new to azure hub notification. I have a search to find some users and sends notification to them. 
When each user registers in the app, we register them individually with azure hub as well.
Then after search, there is a list of deviceIds to which I need to send a push message. At the moment I am using the free tier of azure hub.

The simplest way I can think of is to use foreach and call "SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync" to send a message individually, although it is not an efficient way.

Can anyone please suggest a good approach to send bulk push messages using free hub. If not, what would the alternative be to send bulk message using basic tier. 
Could you please provide an example too.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Notification Hubs now only support [Batch send notifications to device](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/push-notification-hubs-batch-direct-send/). You could [Send notifications to specific users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification).

The Direct Batch Send API is available for **Basic** and **Standard** tier. Users of this API do not need to use Registrations or Installations. Instead, users of this API manage all devices on their own and use Azure Notification Hub solely as a pass through service to communicate with the various Push Notification Services.

At this time, **[Direct Batch Send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt734910(v=azure.100)) supports up to 1000 devices per request**.

If you still want to send bulk notification to users, you could go to this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/218849-notification-hubs) to provide your feedback.